# Error using class derived from C# CheckedListBox to deal with missing descenders

Tags: c#, custom-component

Following the Microsoft suggestion to deal with the problem of descenders not being visible on items shown in a CheckedListBox Object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemheight(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    public sealed class MyListBox : CheckedListBox
    {
        public MyListBox()
        {
            ItemHeight = 20;
        }
        public override int ItemHeight { get; set; }

    }
```

If I add this code outside the  class as follows:

```
namespace SetTags
{

    public partial class SetTags : Form
    {
     ....
    }

    public sealed class MyListBox : CheckedListBox
    {
        public MyListBox()
        {
            ItemHeight = 20;
        }
        public override int ItemHeight { get; set; }

    }
  }
```

I can see MyListBox in the list of SetTags components in Toolbox and am able to add it to a form in design view, and set its name to chkListTags2.

However, when I try to build the project I get an error as follows:

```
SetTags.Designer.cs(55,45,55,54): error CS0426: 
The type name 'MyListBox' does not exist in the type 'SetTags.SetTags'
```

Viewing SetTags.Designer.cs I see the problem is in the line

```
this.chkListTags2 = new SetTags.MyListBox();
```

If I edit this to

```
  this.chkListTags2 = new MyListBox();
```

the build error goes away but recurs when SetTags.Designer is automatically rebuilt.

Is there a way of adding the new sealed class without producing the build error?

I am using VS 2013 in  Win10 environment.

Comment: The name is ambiguous, could be SetTags.MyListBox or could be SetTags.SetTags.MyListBox.  The compiler picks the latter since it is "closest".  That usually pans out well, but it is not the one you want here.  Picking a namespace name that is different from the Form class name is best.  Or just move the class in its own namespace.  Do keep in mind that picking 20 for the item height will not pan out well on another machine with a different DPI setting.  Which is what caused this problem in the first place.  Fixed in .NET 4.7 btw.

Comment: Tried moving class into its own namespace and this worked. Also changed height setting to ItemHeight = base.ItemHeight + 2;